# 301 error when checking nginx_status

Tags: curl, nginx, zabbix

Zabbix shows 301 error when trying to get nginx_status.

This is how my **zabbix.conf** looks like:

```
server {

listen [::]:80;
server_name 127.0.0.1;
location /nginx_status {
    stub_status on;
    access_log off;
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    deny all;
    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/nginx_status_error.log;
}

location ~ ^/(status|ping)$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:7777;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $fastcgi_script_name;
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    deny all;
    }

}
```

When I try to curl I get this error:

```
$ curl 127.0.0.1:80/status
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

There is no messages in **/var/log/nginx/nginx_status_error.log**

I am not sure why this is happaning and where to find root cause. What should I do or check to get rid of this error?

**EDIT:**

```
$ curl -i 127.0.0.1:80/status
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 21 Oct 2019 11:01:17 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 162
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://127.0.0.1/status

<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

**SOLUTION:**

I commented `listen [::]:80;` and add port to `server_name 127.0.0.1:80;`. 
Now I get:

```
$ curl -i 127.0.0.1:80/status
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Comment: Please give the output of `curl -i 127.0.0.1:80/status` so we can see where it wants to redirect, maybe it's only trying to redirect from `/status` to `/status/` or something like that?

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz I updated my post adding `curl -i` output.

Comment: Oh, you seem to have a redirect that forces everything to encrypted https connections. (But connecting to `https://127.0.0.1/status` is very likely to give you a certificate error since no reputable source will issue certificates for `127.0.0.1`.)

Comment: You're right, thanks! Where can I change this? Should I add `server_name http://127.0.0.1/` to force http?

Comment: Welcome, You can answer your question instead of editing.

Comment: You can use `-L` option to advice `curl` to follow redirections.